# What is the unique energy of Tishrei that corresponds to Sukkot?

Tags: sources-mekorot, sukkot, months, nissan, tishrei

Ramchal and many others teach that every moed/festival/zman has a certain energy that it brings down with it, and every year we can access that particular force to serve Hashem in the relevant way.

The verse (Emor 23 43) says "Basukkot hoshavti et Bnei Yisrael" which is referring to right after leaving Egypt, in the month of Nissan. It would seem, then, that we ought to celebrate Sukkot in Nissan, yet we celebrate it in Tishrei.

The Tur (Orach Chaim 625) and the Aruch HaShulchan (Orach Chaim 625 5) both ask the question about celebrating Sukkot in the wrong month, and they give different answers.  The Tur says that if we celebrated it in Nisan, which is in spring, nobody would recognise it as a mitzvah, because everyone goes out in the spring. Therefore we celebrate it in Tishrei, the autumn, to make it apparent that we are doing it for the sake of the mitzvah. The Aruch HaShulchan answers that since Sukkot is a festival of tremendous joy, the most appropriate time to celebrate it would be after Yom Kippur, when we are cleansed from our sins, and Hashem can shower us with love.

Neither of these answers addresses the point of every festival having an energy uniquely associated with that specific time.

My question:
**What unique energy does Tishrei have, that would make it appropriate to celebrate Sukkot then instead of in Nissan?
Please bring sources.**

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why is the energy not in Tishrei?

Comment: Because the Torah says they sat in Sukkot in Nissan @DoubleAA

Comment: What does that have to do with the energy? Isn't the energy whenever the holiday is?

Comment: @AKayser They sat in sukkos the whole year, for a while....

Comment: The Torah was given in Sivan. Could we celebrate Shavuot in Iyar? @DoubleAA

Comment: @Shokhet I have heard that answer before, and although I think it technically answers the question, it is not so satisfying, as we could potentially then celebrate sukkot all year round

Comment: The energy is not whenever the holiday is, the holiday is wherever the energy is @DoubleAA

Comment: @AKayser We can celebrate Shavuot on either 5, 6 or 7 Sivan. I don't understand your last comment. The holiday is whenever God said it should be. If you think holidays must match with energy then I can come up with a really good algorithm to find out where the energy is... What makes you think the energy is not in Tishrei? That's when God said the holiday is, right?

Comment: Cant remember exact sources, but last comment was referring to the fact that when the world was created, all the mazalot (or energies) where set in place. When the events of history took place, it was a revelation of the mazal present. Thats why Avraham ate matzot (before Pesach ever took place). If that is so, when an event occurs in the Torah, it is a revelation of the mazal of that time. Wrt Shavout, that is of course true, but my point is that you can't celebrate it on a different month entirely. This is what the Tur and Aruch Hashulchan were picking up on @DoubleAA

Comment: Sounds like you are asking from a very specific understanding of energies and such. Perhaps you should include in your questions what specific assumptions you are making.

Comment: I think the question needs to be reframed as, "What is the unique energy of Tishrei that corresponds to Sukkoth?"  This way, those who know what you're talking about will be drawn to the question, and those who don't won't be confused by it.  I'm making the appropriate edit; feel free to revert if you disagree, but please understand that the question as written is currently very confusing to the point of being almost irrelevant - if not unanswerable.

Comment: @SethJ see my comment to the answer below, I think the link I pasted asks the question I was trying to ask, in a clearer way

Comment: @AKayser, I cannot open the link. I'll try again later, but in the meantime, does my edit work for your purposes? It makes more sense to me this way, but I'm not familiar with your premise, so I can't be sure.

Comment: @SethJ the edit was helpful, thank you. Although I was asking the other way around- how could we not celebrate in Nissan

Comment: re-asked differently at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/117525/170

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've heard that after the sin of the Golden Calf, the Clouds of Glory were taken away. After Yom Kippur, Moshe told the Jews to start donating for the Mishkan. On Sukkos, all the necessary materials were obtained, and the Clouds of Glory returned.

Comment: I just found this online, which is a very thorough answer to the question http://www.dafyomi.co.il/parsha/sukkot4.htm

Comment: תשרי could be translated as an imperative feminine form of rest or dwell, I think. A command to the שכינה to return to the nation, perhaps? +1

Answer (score 2):

There is a mashal that I am giving from memory.

A king was warned that the queen would have a daughter who would die unless the first man that she saw would be at her wedding. He built a castle and the queen gave birth to the daughter there. The castle was staffed only with women and the queen often visited, telling the king how beautiful and accomplished she was. Of course, rumors grew up around the daughter and when it came time for her to marry very few of the nobles were willing to take the risk. One of the nobles was willing to marry her and did so. Some months later, he came to the king and asked to be allowed to have a massive celebration of his marriage. He explained that even though he had trusted the king, it was only now after some months of marriage that he appreciated how beautiful and intelligent a wife he had.

Similarly, it is only some time later after studying the Torah and being involved in it that we can appreciate what we have and actually feel the simcha of the gift that Hashem has given us.

Answer (score 0):

Peasch- chesed
Shavuot - din/gevurah
{ Succot - tiferet
Purim - Netzach
Chanuka - Hod
https://www.simpletoremember.com/media/a/chanuka-and-midda-of-hod/

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Yaakov and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. It might be worth expanding on your answer so it is self-understandable without having to look up the reference. Great to have you learn with us!